# How to evaluate Ternary string expression and identify value

Tags: c#, regex, expression, conditional-operator

value = 14000;

ternary string expression is "*value > 20000 ? 200 :  value > 15000 && value < 19999 ? 150 : 100* "

**Ans should be 100**

Is there any ways to evaluate expression?

Comment: For the record, that expression is going to evaluate to 100 if `value` is 19999 or 20000 but I suspect that it should be 150. The `value < 19999` part should probably be `value <= 20000` but, in that case, it's redundant anyway and the whole expression should be `value > 20000 ? 200 : value > 15000 ? 150 : 100`. You already know that `value` is less than or equal to 20000 if you get to the second comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Scripting APIs](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) to evaluate the expressions.

The scripting APIs enable .NET applications to instatiate a C# engine and execute code snippets against host-supplied objects and would require `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting` package.

For example,

```
var globals = new Global();
var str = "value > 20000 ? 200 : value > 15000 && value < 19999 ? 150 : 100 ";
var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(str,globals:globals);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Where Global is defined as

```
public class Global
{
    public int @value = 14000;
}
```

[Working Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CXU6a3)